# Setting up a second Angular application on same server using NGINX

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx

I currently have a AngularJS application running on my virtual private server. To run this I'm using NGINX, Node and 'http-server' and pm2 to keep everything running.

So I start my backend using for example 'node server.js' (port 3000) and I setup a second process of 'http-server' (which I think runs on port 8080) in the public folder.

This is the configuration of my NGINX:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name mywebsite.be;

location /{
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
}
}
```

Now I would like to setup a second application which is made with Angular (2). I'm trying to also run my backend with node on port 3001 and then starting http-server on port 8081.

How should I configure my NGINX?

Comment: Questions on **professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about).

Comment: You need to use different virtual hosts for the same. Instead of `mywebsite.be` use `app2.mywebsite.be` and create a new server block for the same. This is the easiest way to get setup

Comment: Ok, can I then just keep the same 'listen' port in the file of the new server? I'll give it a try this evening :)